# iOS _OBJC_CLASS_$_THCircularProgressView referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, linker-errors

IOS App works in Simulator but when I try to run on device (IPhone 5) it fails and I get the following error:

```
"OBJC_CLASS_$_THCircularProgressView" referenced from:
objc-class-ref in viewcontroller.o
Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Linker Command failed with exit code 1
```

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'UIImage+ImageWithColor', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SHPieChartView', '~> 1.0.3'
pod 'THCircularProgressView', '~> 0.1'## MBProgressHUD
```

Pods.Debug.config

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/MBProgressHUD" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SHPieChartView" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/THCircularProgressView" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/UIImage+ImageWithColor"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/MBProgressHUD" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SHPieChartView" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/THCircularProgressView" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/UIImage+ImageWithColor"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"Pods-MBProgressHUD" -l"Pods-SHPieChartView" -l"Pods-THCircularProgressView" -l"Pods-UIImage+ImageWithColor" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "UIKit"
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

pods.environment.h

```
// MBProgressHUD
#define COCOAPODS_POD_AVAILABLE_MBProgressHUD
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MAJOR_MBProgressHUD 0
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MINOR_MBProgressHUD 9
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_PATCH_MBProgressHUD 1

// SHPieChartView
#define COCOAPODS_POD_AVAILABLE_SHPieChartView
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MAJOR_SHPieChartView 1
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MINOR_SHPieChartView 0
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_PATCH_SHPieChartView 3

// THCircularProgressView
#define COCOAPODS_POD_AVAILABLE_THCircularProgressView
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MAJOR_THCircularProgressView 0
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MINOR_THCircularProgressView 1
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_PATCH_THCircularProgressView 1

// UIImage+ImageWithColor
#define COCOAPODS_POD_AVAILABLE_UIImage_ImageWithColor
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MAJOR_UIImage_ImageWithColor 1
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_MINOR_UIImage_ImageWithColor 2
#define COCOAPODS_VERSION_PATCH_UIImage_ImageWithColor 0
```

Comment: are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: @ppaulojr yes we are using cocoapods

Comment: Thank you for the information! And, what's the question?

Comment: so it would be useful to share your Podfile here. Also make sure you opened the .xcworkspace and not the .xcproj

Comment: @ppaulojr i have opened the .xcworkspace only.Also which pod file do i share pods.debug.xconfig ?

Comment: the main `Podfile` where you import stuff

Comment: @ppaulojr question is updated please check

Comment: that's not it. I mean the `Podfile`

Comment: The error would suggest the library containing that class was built for the simulator CPU architectures but not the device CPU architectures.  Find the library the object lives in and from the command line type `file /path/to/library.a` and post the results in your question.